# How can I safely extend my surge protector's cable?

Tags: extension

Here is my situation, my office table doesn't have an outlet nearby, so I need a power strip with a long cable.

I want to use a surge protector for extra protection, and I have one from Brennenstuhl, but its cable  is not long enough. My first thought was to open it up and replace the cable, but it is soldered in places and I don't want to mess with that.

I am thinking however to cut the cable and extend it manually with a cable of my needed length.

**Can I do that to a surge protector?**

Another benefit will be that I can change the plug, so that it connects to the ground in the socket. I am in Denmark and the socket is type K while the surge protector now has type F.
[image]
[image]

If this would be a simple power cord I would do it without asking, but because it's a surge protector I think it's better to ask.

Right now my setup is two power cords one in another one.

Comment: _"so that it connects to the ground in the socket"_ -- if the current cord for the surge protector doesn't have a ground pin, what makes you think that there's a connection inside the surge protector for one? (I've never heard of a surge protector without a ground pin, so that seems odd to me in any case). More to the point though, it's not clear why you don't just use an extension cord. Why the interest in modifying the surge protector itself? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I know that many laptop power supplies don't have grounded power cords, but not having one on a surge suppressor seems... odd.... Are you sure this is an actual surge suppressor, not just a plain "power strip"? (Not Danish, never been there, though it's on the list, so I don't know the brand name.)

Comment: The surge protector has ground, but it connects through the F type plug, while the socket is of type K. I'll add pictures

Comment: @peter-duniho is it safe to plug the surge protector into an extension cord?

Comment: It's safe as long as you don't exceed the rating for the extension cord. You'll want to get a heavy-duty cord, rather than one of those light-weight cords meant for a lamp, bedside clock, etc., but otherwise it will be fine. Do I understand correctly that the F type plug has ground, but the ground pin is on the socket, rather than the plug itself? I.e. the plug has "male" pins for power, but "female" receptacle for ground? (It looks like the F plug is compatible with F receptacle _and_ E receptacle, with the pin being used for E, and the two outer contacts for ground with the F.)

Comment: Do they make adapters for type K plugs to transfer the ground to a type E receptacle? If so, I'd think that would be the way to go. Either `Suppressor -> Adapter -> Extension Eord -> Wall` or `Suppressor -> Extension Cord -> Adapter -> Wall`, depending on what kind of extension cord(s) you currently have/purchase for purpose.

Comment: Are there different electrical standards for the two different plug types? Here in the US, common household 120v @ 15 or 20a plugs are 2 blades and a round pin for ground, but 240v connectors are totally different to _prevent_ insertion and letting the magic smoke out. If those plugs are designed for different voltages, my suggestion obviously won't work...

Comment: @freeman everything over there is 230V derived from 400V 3-phase wye, the only exception is you will sometimes see 400V single-phase or 400V delta.  (yes, in residences). Since that brings them almost at par with our industrial 480V, there’s little need for anything else until you get into heavy industrial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the power supply cord to a cord of the length you desire, and apply the correct plug to the cord. Either by buying a long cord with the correct molded plug already installed... or by buying *cordage* and then installing the appropriate plug.

Rather than solder the wires, leave 100mm or so of length of the old wires inside the strip, and splice Inside, with those lovely screw splices Europeans normally use for in-junction-box splices.

I would not attempt to splice a longer cord onto the cord that is now on it, as that would involve external in-cord splices which will snag and suffer damage and can fail dangerously (either kindling a fire, or shock hazard).

While an extension cord with the correct plug-socket would be tempting, I would not do it; most authorities frown on extension cords for semi-permanent installations.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly:

- You have a surge protector that has [an F type plug](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeF.htm) on it. This plug has a ground connector, but currently the ground is not in use, because you are plugging it into [a K type receptacle](https://www.iec.ch/worldplugs/typeK.htm) (a receptacle that's compatible for the power pins but which doesn't have the right connections for ground).
- You would like to extend the cord. As an added benefit, you would like to make the ground connection, and feel that replacing the cord with one that has a K type plug on it would solve both problems at once.

Depending on the construction of the surge protector, this is probably "fine". Your challenges will be finding a cord of the appropriate length with the plug you want, and opening the surge protector to change the wire. If the surge protector uses screws for the case, opening it should be straightforward. If it's glued, as some cheaper-built ones would be, it's probably not worth the effort.

Inside the surge protector you may find that the cord is soldered, or it may be attached with screws. If the latter, replacement is very easy. If the cord is soldered, that could be harder; high-current wires are soldered with higher-temperature solder and with a larger amount of solder, which means a normal hobbyist soldering iron might not work that well. I've managed to deal with those kinds of connections, but it's a pain and is messy (I'm not that skilled at soldering, and it's easy to overheat neighboring components, circuit board, etc. in the process of trying to disconnect the old cable and solder back on the new one).

**I wouldn't do any of that.**

For your situation, I would instead just use an extension cord. You want something heavy-duty, with 12 gauge wire, not a light-weight lamp cord extension. With an appropriate-sized extension cord, there will be no problem at all.

I don't know what the types of extension cords available in Denmark are, but given the mix of outlets in the country, it's possible you can find an extension cord with an F receptacle end, and a K plug, solving both problems at once.

If not, then surely there are electrical adapters available which can convert the F plug to a K plug, which you can use in conjunction with the extension cord to provide the added length and the ground connection you want.

That will be just as safe, and doesn't involve having to modify the surge protector at all. It's not quite as pretty, but there are fewer opportunities to mess things up. To me, that makes it a much preferable solution. :)